# get_dummies-кодирование и PCA

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, feature-engineering

В задаче регессии обработал один и тот же набор данных двумя разными способами. В одном использовал label_encoder() и передал на обучение, а во втором случае использовал pd.get_dummies() и так как как фрейм 'раздулся' решил использовать PCA. Указал описание дисперсии - 0.99. В моем понимании во втором случае должно было быть улучшение результатов, но это не так. Получил ухудшение почти в 3 раза. Можете подсказать, в каком случае нужно использовать dummies и PCA, а в каким это только вредит?

Comment: "Передал на обучение" - какой модели? Это важно. Во втором случае на обучение передавались только фичи, полученные через PCA? Ну, значит, через PCA плохо разделяются данные, такое тоже бывает. И обычно PCA используют не вместо исходных данных, а в дополнение к ним. А если вы использовали и dummy features и PCA, значит фичи сильно созависимы, а модель к этому не устойчива. В общем - нужно больше деталей, чтобы дальше что-то советовать.

Comment: Да, и, конечно, нужно не забывать про кросс-валидацию и т.д., возможно произошло переобучение. Тонкостей там много разных. И универсальных методов нет, всегда нужно пробовать разные подходы и смотреть, какие хорошо работают на ваших конкретных данных.

Comment: Линейной регрессии и Ридж. ''И обычно PCA используют не вместо исходных данных, а в дополнение к ним.'' - я думал при помощи PCA наоборот уменьшают размерность. То есть если у меня после get_dummies() оказывается 300 фичей, применяя PCA с описанием дисперсии 0.99 он показывает мне 200 фичей... И я должен их совместить? Это разве не дублирование? Мультиколлинеарность? Извиняюсь, если что-то не так понял...

Comment: House prices на Kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

Comment: @ЕгорОвчинников Нет, ну если данные хорошо разделяются через PCA, то отлично, конечно. Но нужно подбирать число компонент и, возможно, убирать не все исходные dummy фичи. Про мультиколлинеарность вы правы, и для деревянных к примеру моделей лишние фичи - это лишние уровни дерева, это тоже плохо. Но PCA в любом случае - не панацея от всего, а просто дополнительные фичи, которые могут полностью заменить исходные, а могут и не заменить.

Comment: На сколько я узнал из различных источников, в том числе из документации, что если число компонентов от 0 до 1, то это рассматривается как желаемый диапазон дисперсии, а если от 1 и выше, то уже предпочитаемое количество фичей... От сюда вопрос(глупый, но лучше задам)... Что лучше указывать, размер дисперсии или количество фичей?

Comment: И линейной регрессией тоже надо уметь пользоваться - правильно заменять NaN, правильно скейлить, убирать мультиколлинеарность, да. Я не силён в статистике, поэтому про .99 дисперсии вам ничего ответить не могу. У меня чисто инженерный подход - надо придумывать фичи, отбирать, пробовать. Я немного знаю, как какие модели работают, но со статистикой несколько "плаваю".

Comment: А не подскажешь еще, каким образом можно посмотреть хорошо или плохо разделяются данные через PCA... Это мой первый опыт использования PCA.